# get two elements from list simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I am new to python and I want to iterate two elements from the same list simultaneously  in fashion `s-> (s0,s1)(s1,s2)(s2,s3)(s3,s4)....`

I have tried using `itertools` but it is printing in following fashion `s-> (s0,s1)(s2,s3)(s4,s5).....`.

How can I do it?

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a = iter(iterable)
    return itertools.zip_longest(a,a)

for x,y in pairwise(combined):
...
```

Code which i used but it is not showing results as required.thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
l1 = ["s0","s1","s2","s3","s4"]
l2 = []
if(len(l1) <= 1):
    l2 = l1
else:
    for i in range(len(l1)-1):
        l2.append([l1[i],l1[i+1]])
print l2
```

Answer (score 1):

use you can use zip for this

```
list_ = [i  for i in range(10)]
result =[(a,b) for a,b in zip(list_,list_[1:])]
print(result)
```

output

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

if you want a little fast than here is one

```
list_ = [i  for i in range(10)]
result= = [(list_[i],list_[i-1]) for i in range(1,len(list_))]
print(result)
```

output

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

Comment: will it increase my execution time a lot because i have a list of 84 lakhs elements

Comment: this will solve your problem, for rest thing you need to modify your question fully so other can know what are you trying to achive

Comment: @Bhavin Thakar  `l[0:]` and `l[1:]` will each make copies of `l`. Those are the most expensive things here.

Comment: Can you explain this @temmo

Comment: `zip(l,l[1:])` will suffice.  Just avoid using `l` as name since it looks similar to `1` or `I` (i).

Comment: @pylang   yes `zip(l,l[1:])` is suffice but for learning purpose i put `zip(l[0:],l[1:])`.  i changed the `l` to `list_` .

Comment: If you wish, but `l[0:]` creates an extra copy of the list.  The is what @Carcigenicate is hinting at.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pairwise` [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), which yields overlapping pairs:

**Given**

```
import itertools as it
```

**Code**

```
def pairwise(seq):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2,s3), ..."""
    a, b = it.tee(seq)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

**Demo**

```
list(pairwise(["s0", "s1", "s2", "s3"]))
# [('s0', 's1'), ('s1', 's2'), ('s2', 's3')]
```

**See Also**

- [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools): a third-party [package](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) that implements [`pairwise`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.pairwise), `itertools` [recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and more.

Answer (score 0):

zip is indeed quite expensive in this case.
You can use a local variable

```
l = range(10)

a = l[0];
for b in l[1:]:
    print(a, b)
    a = b
```

gives:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
```

of course you can fix the `l[1:]` to prevent a copy